# get request header from ServletContextEvent

Tags: servlets, cookies

I made a listener, which sets secure flag on cookie, according [set secure flag on cookie programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163824/how-to-set-secure-flag-on-cookie-programatically)
And I want to enable or disable this flag automatically as in [secure flag on session cookies in a java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23998597/secure-flag-on-session-cookies-in-a-java-web-application)
How to get request from ServletContextEvent? Is it other way to do it?

```
public class SecureCookieServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final String LB_HTTPS_HEADER = "Front-End-Https";

    @Override public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
        final String httpsHeader = request.getHeader(LB_HTTPS_HEADER);
        boolean secure = httpsHeader != null && httpsHeader.equalsIgnoreCase("on");

        sce.getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig().setSecure(secure);
    }   
}
```

Comment: No, you can't get a request from the ServletContextEvent, and it's not meaningful to want to do that since it is _"the event class for notifications about changes to the servlet context of a web application"_. All the ServletContextEvent can give you is the [ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html), and you can't get the request from that either. See the accepted answer to [How can I get HttpServletRequest from ServletContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31492792/2985643) for a full explanation.

Comment: @skomisa Grand thanks.